# Scraping text from HTML5 website using Python

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping

I need to way to scrape just the text from a website using python. I have installed BeautifulSoup 4, HTML Requests, and NLTK but I just can't seem to find out how to scrape.

I really need a simple snippet of code that I can plug any URL into and get the plain text. I'm trying to get it from [this website](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Hammer_Selection_Tool)

Comment: Consider putting more information and codes in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BeautifulSoup can extract all the texts from a page easily. The following is an example to extract texts inside the `<body>`...`</body>` section.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from contextlib import closing

url = 'https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Hammer_Selection_Tool'
with closing(urllib.urlopen(url)) as h:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(h.read())

print soup.body.get_text()
```